# Podio C# first time using API can't authenticate with password

Tags: c#, authentication, podio

I installed the Podio Async package into a Windows Forms App I created using Visual Studio 2019. I had set up the API Key in the settings and I can't get app to authenticate.

```
var podio = new Podio(clientId, clientSecret);
```

it seems to hang at

```
await podio.AuthenticateWithPassword("myPodioLoginEmailAddress","myLoginPassword");
```

Not sure how to test what's wrong. Also, I don't have a secure URL to test this with so, I set the return URL to localhost which was a suggestion I found on another post.

Comment: You mean code after this line never gets executed?

Comment: What error you are getting when the authentication fails?. Is it TLS related?

Comment: I'm not getting an error because after waiting a minute, I just break out of the program. I'll look into the TLS issue but, I think that was resolved as of .Net 4.51. I'm wondering if I can use "localhost" for the domain name.

Answer (score 0):

Finally had a chance to return to this and solved my problem. I was trying from a simple Windows Form button click. I got it working by creating a console app and calling the await statement in an async Task

public static async Task Init()
{